# store GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY data to CPU

Tags: opengl, texture

I have a GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY texture of 8 cube maps (`countLayers`). Now I am trying to transfer the pixels to CPU.

Currently I am using this code:

```
unsigned int countFloats = size * size * countChannels * 6 * countLayers;
pixels = new float[countFloats];

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, colorTexture()->id());
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, pixels);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, 0);
```

It seems like, that this code works only for the first cubemap within the array. Because when deleting the multiplication with `countLayers` in the first line, everything is still working. But when `pixels` does not have enough storage (for example deleting the factor `6` as well), the program is crashing.

How can I store all cube maps to CPU? It would also be okay to store each cube map separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake...
I was creating 6 cube maps, not 8... but when creating them I have to multiply the number of wanted cube maps by 6 which I didn't done. So the cube map array texture was only holding one cube map.

```
glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY, 1, ToGlInternalFormat(format), size, size, layer); // this layer variable needs to be multiplied by 6
```

So the source code I posted within the question is working fine.